# Jenkins: Create and Pass SVN Tag to ANT and Subversion Tagging Plugin

Tags: svn, jenkins

I'm trying to use the `BUILD_NUMBER` environment property to create a tag that I can pass down to my ANT script (so that I can write it to my WAR/JAR manifest) as well as use it during the tagging process executed by the "Subversion Tagging Plugin".

A minor complication is that I'd like to zero-pad the `BUILD_NUMBER` before using it. For example, if the `BUILD_NUMBER` is 14, my tag would look like 1.0.0.00014.

I've found the EnvInject plugin which has an "Evaluated Groovy script" feature and this script works for me, but I do have questions:

```
import jenkins.model.*

def tagPrefix = "1.0.0."
def env = Jenkins.instance.getItem("BnL Build").getLastBuild().getEnvironment()
def buildNumber = env['BUILD_NUMBER']
def tag = tagPrefix + buildNumber.padLeft(5,'0')

def map = [AP_SVN_TAG: tag]

return map
```

Questions are:

- Is the EnvInject option even the best way to go for what I want to do?
- Is there a more direct API to get "this build" than via `Jenkins.instance.getItem()`? I know that works, but seems fragile given that the Job's name could change at any time and thus break the script. I tried `manager.build.getEnvironment(manager.listener)['BUILD_NUMBER']` instead, but I got an error that `[EnvInject] - [ERROR] - SEVERE ERROR occurs: No such property: manager for class: Script1`.

If it helps I'm running Jenkins v1.488, Jenkins Subversion Tagging Pluging v1.16 and Environment Injector Pluging v1.73.

Thanks in advance,

Matt

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The plugin has now been updated to version 1.75 by gboissinot and makes the variables `currentJob` and `currentBuild` available to the Groovy script. So my new Groovy script is:

```
import jenkins.model.*

def tagPrefix = "1.0.0."
def buildNumber = currentBuild.getNumber().toString()
def tag = tagPrefix + buildNumber.padLeft(5,'0')

def map = [AP_SVN_TAG: tag]

return map
```

And it works great!